# Ссылки на объекты PHP

Tags: php, ссылки

Я использовал в своём коде ссылки на объекты, передавал их функции, т.е.

```
 <?php IniModule(&$site,'register'); ?>
```

Где `$site` - экземпляр класса. Но сбросив это на мой локальный сервер, на планшете мне выдало ошибку:

> `"call-time pass-by-reference has been removed"`.

Означает она, что ссылки устарели. Почему? Чем заменить? Объект получается передавать?

Comment: там-же в доке написано, что теперь это решает только сама функция в объявлении. http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.references.pass.php

Comment: Ааа, понял, спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ссылку на объект? Зачем? Объект и так не по значению передается. Можно его успешно изменять внутри функции.